# Cannot install addon because the site reports I'm on FF52 while I'm using FF57

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm trying to install the [Reddit Enhancement Suite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reddit-enhancement-suite/) addon. When I visit this page I see the following warning:

> This add-on requires a newer version of Firefox (at least version 53.0). You are using Firefox 52.0.

I'm using Firefox 57. Why does Mozilla think I use Firefox 52?

Comment: maybe manually set useragent?

Comment: To do that you have to add values to about:config. I've never done that. I don't have a user agent switcher addon.

Answer (score 1):

[According to this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/7cww81/quantum_developer_edition_580b1_reporting/), you need to open `about:config` and reset the option `privacy.resistFingerprinting`.

Maybe you changed it before and just don't remember it, or some extension did it for you.

Comment: If that doesn’t work just chnage your user agent.